# costmap_2d::VoxelLayer not clearing

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello there,

I'm using the move_base navigation stack. I'm realizing that the `costmap_2d::VoxelLayer` doesn't seem to clear up
the costmap when the data are fed from and rgbd sensor.  I'm using the following costmap configuration (I omit the local_costmap and global_costmap parameters, I report only the common parameters)

```
robot_radius: 0.16
plugins:
  - {name: static_layer, type: 'costmap_2d::StaticLayer'}
  - {name: obstacles_layer, type: "costmap_2d::VoxelLayer"}
  - {name: inflation_layer, type: "costmap_2d::InflationLayer"}

obstacles_layer:
  obstacle_range: 1.5
  raytrace_range: 3.0
  observation_sources: rgbd_scan laser_scan 
  rgbd_scan: {sensor_frame: camera_rgb_optical_frame, data_type: PointCloud2, topic: rgbdscan, marking: true, clearing: true, min_obstacle_height: 0.03, max_obstacle_height: 1.00, mark_threshold: 3}
  laser_scan: {sensor_frame: laser_link, data_type: LaserScan, topic: scan, marking: true, clearing: true} 

inflation_layer: 
  inflation_radius: 0.7
  cost_scaling_factor: 20.0
```

Clearing doesn't work!

Regards,
Federico

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/197664/costmap_2d::voxellayer-not-clearing/) by [Federico](https://answers.ros.org/users/18920/federico/) on ROS Answers with karma: 100 on 2014-11-18

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

After studying the code of `costmap_2d::VoxelLayer` I found the reason why.

Apparently, the clearing strategy implemented in the VoxelLayer works fine, however, when the points in the clouds that don't lie in the range `min/max_obstacle_range` are removed from the observation set so, for instance, if you set a `min_obstacle_height` to filter the floor, the observation of the floor are removed and no clearing is applied.

---

Originally posted by [Federico](https://answers.ros.org/users/18920/federico/) with karma: 100 on 2014-11-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AReimann](https://answers.ros.org/users/20356/areimann/) on 2014-11-25**:
We circumvented that by adding the rgb_scan twice as observation source. One with marking which has a min_obstacle_height heigher than the floor. The other one with only clearing which has a min_bstacle_height lower than the floor

**Comment by [Federico](https://answers.ros.org/users/18920/federico/) on 2014-11-25**:
Thanks for your suggestion. I'll try it but I think that the VoxelLayer now treats each observation independently so that clearing and marking are applied to each observation source without affecting the others. Anyway, I can be wrong.